# set numeric input type to SearchView in ActionBar

Tags: android, input, android-actionbar, searchable, keypad

I don't manage to set the numeric input type to the SearchView in my ActionBar. I have the following **searchable.xml** file in my **res/xml** folder:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint">
</searchable>
```

And I set the searchable configuration to the SearchView as follows:

```
 // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
 SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)    getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
 SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
 searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

The search_hint is set correctly, but the line **android:inputType="number"** seems to have no effect, i.e. the numeric keypad doesn't appear.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Solved the problem by using a custom EditText instead of a SearchView.

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your searchable.xml layout file:

```
android:numeric="decimal"
```

or If not useful then try,

`android:inputType="phone"`

And let me know what happen.

Comment: numeric is not an attribute of searchable, and unfortunately setting the inputType to phone doesn't help.

Comment: Look at this [Creating a Searchable Configuration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) then this [searchable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html#searchable-element) then [inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#inputType).

Comment: As you can see from my code, the inputType is set to "number" but the numeric keypad doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getContext());
searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: Look like it's working, but only for Android API 14+. Am I right? (Question doesn't specify API version anyway)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
android:inputType="phone"
```

Comment: It seems that digits is not an attribute of searchable.

Comment: dohh, forgot this, it is applied for edittext. Anyway ,with inputType phone, the numeric keyboard should appear.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work even with the inputType set to phone. It works for a edittext, but not for the SearchView.